# Explaining an incorrect solution involving derivative of an inverse.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, education, inverse-function, inverse-function-theorem

Suppose $f$ is injective and $f(1)=5$ and $f'(1)=3$. Then a quick application of the inverse function theorem gives $(f^{-1})'(5)=1/3$. However, what is incorrect in the following?:

$$(f^{-1})'(5)=(f^{-1}(5))'=f'(1)=3$$

My question is, how do I explain to a student that the first equality above is incorrect?

Comment: Downvoter: please explain your downvote so I may improve the question.

Comment: You might try to unpack why the student thinks either the first or second equation is correct. As I see it, $f^{-1}(5) = 1,$ so $(f^{-1}(5))'=(1)'=0.$ The first equation just seems like an arbitrary shuffling of symbols to me; it makes as much sense as $f^{-1}(5)=f(5^{-1}).$

Comment: @DavidK Okay, the latter is a good analogous example. I struggled with explaining the arbitrary shuffling of symbols, as you effectively called it.

Comment: I would say the second equality, $(f^{-1}(5))'=f'(1)$, is also incorrect. What we actually have is $$(f^{-1})'(5)\not=(f^{-1}(5))'=(1)'=0=(5)'=(f(1))'\not=f'(1)=3$$

Answer (score 3):

The error is in the step

$$(f^{-1})'(5) = (f^{-1}(5))'$$

Let $f^{-1} = g$

$$\implies g'(5) = (g(5))'$$

What you have on the left hand side is the value of the derivative of the inverse evaluated at $x=5$. What you have on the right doesn't make sense - you are taking the derivative of an instance of the function at a point - which makes no sense, as you can only define a derivative of a function

I'm not sure what grade this is being discussed in, but if derivatives have been introduced I'm assuming there is an understanding of the basics of limits and differentiability

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know such questions seldom have useful answers, this is an exception.